# Most common derivation Paths, accounts and indexes

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets

can anyone tell me what the most used derivation paths are? Someone on reddit wrote that coinbase use this path: `m/44'/0'/0'/0/0`. Do other companies use the same path?

Also do big companies always start generating keys/addresses from account 0 and index 0 aka as on the picture from [learnmeabitcoin.com](https://learnmeabitcoin.com) the coin type (is default 0 for bitcoin?), account 0, receiving 0 and key generation from index 0?

My last question is what the "Change" structure is used for? As I understand "Receiving" is for receiving coins but I have no idea what the other one means.

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 1):

[BIP44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki) defines a standard path scheme:

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
```

The BIP defines what coin type, account, change and address index mean. It further specifies that the purpose field is set to `44'` when generating addresses and for bitcoin the coin type is set to `0'`.

At the time when it was written, the only standard address type was P2PKH (addresses starting with `1`). Over the years, more standard derivation paths were added:

- [BIP49](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0049.mediawiki): P2WPKH-nested-in-P2SH (addresses starting with `3`). The purpose field for these is `49'`.
- [BIP84](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0084.mediawiki): P2WPKH (addresses starting with `bc1q`). Purpose field is `84'`.
- [BIP86](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0086.mediawiki): P2TR (addresses starting with `bc1p`). Purpose field is `86'`.

You can check the website https://walletsrecovery.org/ that maintains a list of wallets and which derivation paths they support. As you can see, modern wallets mostly implement the mentioned standard paths (although apparently the website hasn't been updated for BIP86).