# Whats the hashing process

Tags: hash

How can my BTC address "14EWK38NoTu8MDeCf5zWWjXyE7F4xU9S9S" turned into something like "2203c6eae793d27105b3ed165ca7fa76360e9d05e2f3".

what is the process

Answer (score 2):

The address is a number written in [base58](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding),

the other is a number written in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal).

You can  convert a number from base58 to hexadecimal using a base58 decoder such as [this one](http://lenschulwitz.com/base58) or many others. You will see that 14EWK38NoTu8MDeCf5zWWjXyE7F4xU9S9S in Base58 is 2376409F0007DA4D5FA8C8BBA9FD480B449986BB700BAF7D in hexadecimal

There is no hashing involved. It is just the same number written down in two different ways.

If you want to know how addresses are derived from keys by hashing, see [how does the blockchain addresses relate to the blockchain WIF?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/115203/13866) and [other questions here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=produce+address)