# Are some derivation paths more secure than others?

Tags: wallet, seed, hardened-derivation

I'm planning to create a seed which will be my main BTC "account". I've been reading up on how the private master key is derived from the seed, and how keys are derived from a master private key, and I have a pretty good grasp on how it works.

On thing I've noticed is that every wallet has his own derivation path (I think Electrum uses m/44'/0'/0'/i, Bitcoin core m/0'/0'/i), etc. I don't want to depend on a single wallet and I obviously don't want to remember a specific derivation path on top of the seed. I figured I could just use the path m/i' for my i-th key-pair (no particular reason to use hardened keys, just read somewhere they're a bit more secure).

My questions is: is there a security problem in doing this? If so, why doesn't any wallet do this? (You can look up the derivation paths used by different wallets here: https://walletsrecovery.org/)

Comment: The different derivation paths are for different output script (address) types. I recommend you check out https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/114574/121614.